# Where can I ask this question about IS and IT solutions can improve the effectiveness and efficiency of business?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I need to put this

> It has been believed that “IS and IT solutions can improve the
>   effectiveness and efficiency of business processes.” However,
>   introducing IS and IT will cost money (in some cases millions!)
>   Therefore, how IS and IT solutions can help and at the same time bring
>   extra cost?

to a discussion... Where on Stack Exchange can I put the question?

Comment: What is your question? How can products provide value but also cost money? How can a banana provide value and also cost money? A car? The point of companies building and selling products is to exchange value for money. Having said all that: there is nowhere in the network this question will fit. It is way too broad. A good litmus test for questions like these is if you can describe what you’re seeking in response as “a discussion“, it’s too broad to fit anywhere in the SE model.

Comment: @DanBron.. i didn't ask you to analyze the question .. i asked "where can i put the question?!".

Comment: I answered that question directly, with a clear explanation, and as a free bonus *also* provided an incisive analysis of the question itself. You’re welcome!

Answer (score 4):

SE dosen't do discussion.

There's a few fundamental problems with this as a question - It attempts to ask for the interpretation of a text, which rarely works well.

Firstly [as per the help centre](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)

> You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face. Chatty, open-ended questions diminish the usefulness of our site and push other questions off the front page.

Also as per the [help centre](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions)

> if your question could be answered by an entire book, or has many valid answers (but no way to determine which - if any - are correct), then it is probably too broad for our format

Now, in theory, if you can narrow it down to specific solutions, and specific questions to do with those we could *start* - but I don't actually think there's a site that handles that sort of big picture IT management. Serverfault and Superuser certainly do not, nor do most of the sites I'm familiar with.

So, in its current form, there's no site that it'll fit

Comment: To be clear, this is a question from my doctor in college .. he asked us to discuss it through a discussion board .. and i do not know how to start

Comment: Well, this isn't a discussion board - and its not a good fit for SE cause of the above.

Comment: @jjj In general, StackExchange doesn’t react well to being asked to do someone’s homework for him, nor to questions where the questioner hasn’t shown evidence of his own efforts prior to asking (in other words, SE is not a good fit to ask questions when you don’t know where to start; it’s good for answering questions where you have a baseline understanding, have already started, and got stuck on some point.)

Comment: @DanBron .. well , i didn't ask you to solve my ((homework)) .. i want it to be a discussion just to clear my thoughts about it..!!

Comment: @jjj As the others have said, this isn't a discussion board. Post it on Reddit or a similar site.

Comment: @jjj but what you've done is the equivalent of going into a car showroom and asking to buy a birthday cake. When the salesman says we don't sell cakes you say, but you sell things and I want to buy something so please sell me a birthday cake. At some point you have to realise that you're not going to get a birthday cake here.

Comment: @carciganicate at least your answer more useful than the others.. thanks

Comment: @jjj Everyone has been saying exactly that.  How was everyone else not helpful?

Comment: @ramhoud everyone is saying that our site is not the right place to ask that kind of question..and no one said where to ask ..!